# DocuSign PUT resend_envelope=true

Tags: docusignapi

I am developing something that interfaces with the DocuSign REST API. Sending and voiding envelopes are working fine but I am having trouble trying to resend an envelope.

I am receiving a bad request status response to my PUT invocation (below) intended to 1) correct a bad email address or 2) force a resend because a client entered the incorrect Access Code and put the envelope into an Authentication Failure status.

This is the url (with accountId and envelopdId substituted appropriately in my live application) I am using with a PUT method when I create the request:

```
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients?resend_envelope=true
```

Immediately after creating the request (for testing purposes) I write out the request headers and it looks like the following:

```
X-DocuSign-Authentication: <DocuSignCredentials><Username>omitted</Username><Password>omitted</Password><IntegratorKey>omitted</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
Accept: application/xml
Content-Type: application/xml
Host: demo.docusign.net
```

The request body looks like the following. Note here, I have had several variations of this as suggested by DocuSign Support, with and without an xmlns attribute and with and without the signer node.

```
<signers>
  <signer>
    <name>FName LName</name>
    <email>emailaddr@fake.com</email>
    <recipientId>1</recipientId>
  </signer>
</signers>
```

The bad request response I get is below and the actual envelopeId in the response matches my resend request.

```
<envelopeSummary xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><envelopeId>omitted</envelopeId><status>bad request</status><statusDateTime>6/5/2015 2:41:04 PM</statusDateTime></envelopeSummary>
```

All the above has been reviewed by DocuSign Support but they can provide no opinion as to why the resend request is failing. Support has said that instead of a PUT invocation they see a POST that ends before the envelopeId. Makes no sense.

I would appreciate any feedback as to what might be the problem. Thanks

*****I change to sending my request body as json and was successful at updating the envelopes email address. However, that did not trigger a resend.

*****Just out of curiosity I did a second resend of the envelope and happily it was resent. Curious that the first PUT acted on the correction (changed the bad email address to the corrected email address) but did not cause the envelope to be resent. The second PUT acted on the resend (nothing was changed).

Comment: Can you please try adding the recipients block:  <recipients><signers>
  <signer>
    <name>FName LName</name>
    <email>emailaddr@fake.com</email>
    <recipientId>1</recipientId>
  </signer>
</signers></recipients>

Comment: And agreed its a PUT not a POST.

Comment: Envelope correction is working fine for me, though I've only tested using JSON format and not XML.  I'll post a full working solution in PHP since I'm not sure what language you're using.  As a test try changing to JSON body to see if it's an issue with XML...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working as intended for me, here's a full working solution that creates a new envelope from a template, sends it, then it performs a correction on that in-flight envelope.  I get a success status returned and see in the console the updated recipient information.

```
<?php

    // Input your info here:
    $email = "***";         // your account email (also where this signature request will be sent)
    $password = "***";      // your account password
    $integratorKey = "***";     // your account integrator key, found on (Preferences -> API page)
    $recipientName = "***";     // provide a recipient (signer) name
    $templateId = "***";        // provide a valid templateId of a template in your account
    $templateRoleName = "***";  // use same role name that exists on the template in the console

    // construct the authentication header:
    $header = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" . $email . "</Username><Password>" . $password . "</Password><IntegratorKey>" . $integratorKey . "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // STEP 1 - Login (to retrieve baseUrl and accountId)
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));

    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if ( $status != 200 ) {
        echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status;
        exit(-1);
    }

    $response = json_decode($json_response, true);
    $accountId = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["accountId"];
    $baseUrl = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["baseUrl"];
    curl_close($curl);

    // --- display results
    echo "\naccountId = " . $accountId . "\nbaseUrl = " . $baseUrl . "\n";

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // STEP 2 - Create an envelope from a template and send
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $data = array("accountId" => $accountId, 
        "emailSubject" => "DocuSign API - Signature Request from Template",
        "templateId" => $templateId, 
        "templateRoles" => array( 
                array( "recipientId" => "1234", "email" => $email, "name" => $recipientName, "roleName" => $templateRoleName )),
        "status" => "sent");

    $data_string = json_encode($data);  
    $curl = curl_init($baseUrl . "/envelopes" );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
        "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )                                                                       
    );

    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ( $status != 201 ) {
        echo "ERROR- Status returned = " . $status . "\nerror text is --> ";
        print_r($json_response); echo "\n";
        exit(-1);
    }

    $response = json_decode($json_response, true);
    $envelopeId = $response["envelopeId"];

    // --- display results
    echo "Document is sent! Envelope ID = " . $envelopeId . "\n\n"; 

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // STEP 3 - Perform correction and resend envelope
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    echo "Performing envelope correction...\n";

    $data_string = 
        "{
          \"signers\" :
          [
            {
              \"email\": \"new_email_address\",
              \"name\": \"new_recipient_name\",
              \"recipientId\": \"1234\"
            }
          ]
        }";

    $curl = curl_init($baseUrl . "/envelopes/$envelopeId/recipients" . "?resend_envelope=true" );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
        "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )                                                                       
    );

    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ( $status != 200 ) {
        echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status . "\nerror text is --> ";
        print_r($json_response); echo "\n";
        exit(-1);
    }

    $response = json_decode($json_response, true);

    // --- display results
    echo "Correction result = " . "\n\n" . $json_response. "\n\n"; 
?>
```